# Overriding a method to extend existing function

Tags: c++, inheritance, overriding

I have a class `Child`, inheriting from class `Parent`. Class `Parent` has a virtual protected method `_parentClassMethod(int a, int b)`. This method is used in a method of class `Child`:

```
void Child::_childClassMethod(int c, int d)
{
//some code
_parentClassMethod(int a, int b);
//some more code
}
```

My problem is: in `_parentClassMethod`, there is a function call I need to do differently when called from `Child` class. I am blanking out but is there a better way to do it other than redefining the entire `_parentClassMethod` in `Child` class?

Definition of the parentClassMethod:

```
void Parent::_parentClassMethod(int a, int b){
//lots of other code
setSomethingFunction(val1, val2, val3);/*this function cannot be made virtual since it               writes to the eeprom of a device*/
//lot more code
}
```

Comment: If the function is long, just extract the part that differs into a virtual function.

Comment: Parent should normally be unaware of Child -- just sayin'. maybe you should break your methods up, and put them in the appropriate classes instead.

Comment: If you need to do it differently in the child class, why not implement it in the child class (override the parent's method)?

Comment: @justin Were your parents unaware of you? Lol sorry, just couldn't resist :P

Comment: @LewsTherin of course they were! that's why i communicate with programs in my adult life =p

Comment: @chris: Extracting that part into a virtual function is not possible since it is a macro (which write to an eeprom).

Comment: @LewsTherin well… that *would* take care of the projected demand for programmers over the next few decades :) sorry -- have to play devil's advocate =p

Comment: @justin I wonder why the government never thought of that ha ha

Comment: @armundle And what exactly prevents you, putting this macro into a separate function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define a virtual function in parent and override (thanks @k-ballo) it in the child class.

```
class base {
public:
    virtual void f() { /* do parent thing */ }
    void _parentClassMethod(int a, int b) {
        // something
        f();
        // more stuff
    }
};

class derived : public base {
public:
    virtual void f() { /* do child thing */ }
};
```

Comment: Don't _overload_ it, _override_ it!

Answer (score 6):

If you want to call the parent method from the child method, you can do this:

```
void Child::themethod(int c, int d)
{
    Parent::themethod(c,d);
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to solve this:

1. Override the method/function in the child class.
2. Define a switch to make it behave differently in the parent class's `_parentClassMethod()`

The best way would be to override the function.

What I mean by the 2nd method is:

```
void Parent::_parentClassMethod(int a, int b, int switchx)
{
   switch(switchx){
     case 0:
       /*behave normally*/ break;
     case 1:
       /*behave abnormally*/break;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you cant override setSomethingFunction(), then just override _parentClassMethod().

Comment: I am not sure if overriding _parentClassMethod() for just 1 out of 300 lines of code is the best thing. Therein is the main problem I am facing.

Comment: What about splitting thecode and making virtual a function with the section that calls setSomethingFunction(), 300 lines seem very long for a function anyway don't you think?

Answer (score 0):

There is a design pattern just created for this task: [Template method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern).

Create virtual method calling the method you do not want to make virtual:

```
class Parent {
  virtual void _parentClassMethod(int a, int b);
protected:
  virtual void _parentClassMethodSetSth(val1, val2, val3, ...)
  {
      setSomethingFunction(val1, val2, val3);
  }

};

void Parent::_parentClassMethod(int a, int b){
  //lots of other code
  _parentClassMethodSetSth(val1, val2, val3);
  //lot more code
}
```

And override `_parentClassMethodSetSth` in Child.